# Bridging virtual machines on xen

Tags: networking, xen

I have a dedicated server, running xen and a few virtual machines set up as separate entities with their own IP addresses. I have about 16Gb RAM left, and I would like to create a few more virtual machines, but my provider wouldn't give me more IP addresses. Is there a way to setup xen so that

my current virtual machines work as they used to, on their own IP addresses
my new vms are bridged and I can maybe use HAProxy to redirect traffic to them?

Answer (score 1):

You don't give a great deal of information but you could probably install a router/firewall VM such as pfsense using one of your IPs and then use either the 10.x.x.x or 192.168.x.x range of addresses for your VMs and NAT them with the router.